# MainActor and async await when reading and writing

Tags: swift, concurrency

I understand the new async syntax in Swift in the sense that if I call it, then it will handle a pool of asynchronous queues / threads (whatever) to do the work. What I don't understand is how we return to the main thread once it's all over.

// On main thread now

```
let manager = StorageManager()
let items = await manager.fetch // returns on main thread?

struct StorageManager {
    
    private func read() throws -> [Item] {
        let data = try file.read()
        if data.isEmpty { return [] }
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
    }
    
    func fetch() async {
        fetchAndWait()
    }
    
    func fetchAndWait() {
        if isPreview { return }
        let items = try? read()
        fetchedItems = items ?? []
    }
    
    func save() throws {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(fetchedItems)
        try file.write(data)
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that I read and write from/to disk in the correct way i.e. is thread safe when necessary and concurrent where possible. Is it best to declare this struct as a @MainActor ?

Comment: There is no actual threading or waiting in your example. You might as well just delete the terms `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the code you've given that uses `async` or `await` meaningfully, and there is nothing in the code you've given that goes onto a "background thread", so the question as posed is more or less meaningless. If the question *did* have meaning, the answer would be: to guarantee that code doesn't run on the main thread, put that code into an *actor*. To guarantee that code *does* run on the main thread, put that code into a `@MainActor` object (or call `MainActor.run`).

Answer (score -1):

The `async` methods do not return automatically to the main thread, they either:

1. complete in the background whatever they are doing

or

2. explicitly pass at a certain moment the execution to the main thread through a `@MainActor` function/ class. *(edited following @matt's comment)*

In the code above you can start by correcting the fact that `fetch()` does not return any value (`items` will receive nothing based on your code).

Example of your code for case 1 above:

```
let manager = StorageManager()
let items = await manager.fetch // not on the main thread, the value will be stored in the background

struct StorageManager {
    
    private func read() throws -> [Item] {
        let data = try file.read()
        if data.isEmpty { return [] }
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
    }
    
    func fetch() async -> [Item] {
        if isPreview { return }
        let items = try? read()
        return items ?? []
    }
    
    func save() throws {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(fetchedItems)
        try file.write(data)
    }
}
```

Example for case 2 above (I created an `@Published` var, which should only be written on the main thread, to give you the example):

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    let manager = StorageManager()
    @Published var items = [Item]() // should change value only on main thread

    func updateItems() {
        Task {            // Enter background thread
            let fetchedItems = await self.manager.fetch()

            // Back to main thread
            updateItemsWith(fetchedItems)
        }
    }

    @MainActor private func updateItemsWith(newItems: [Item]) {
        self.items = newItems
    }

}

struct StorageManager {
    
    private func read() throws -> [Item] {
        let data = try file.read()
        if data.isEmpty { return [] }
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
    }
    
    func fetch() async -> [Item] {
        if isPreview { return }
        let items = try? read()
        return items ?? []
    }
    
    func save() throws {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(fetchedItems)
        try file.write(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: You must never speak of DispatchQueue in the new `async/await` environment.

Comment: @matt: Thank you. I went back to WWDC21 videos and understand a bit more myself.